# Can't set two h2 elements side by side

Tags: html, css

I've got problem in simple math with two `<h2>` elements side by side in a form. The form width is 400px. `<h2>` elements are 200px wide including padding but still the same sized `<h2>` (near it) is going onto a new row.

https://jsfiddle.net/9vbqwcm0/1/

```
h2{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
}

h2:first-child{
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #00c;
}

h2:last-of-type{
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
}

<form action="#" method="GET">
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <h2>New account</h2>
        <input type="text" name="Meno" placeholder="Meno">
        <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Heslo">
        <label for="agree">
            <input type="checkbox" name="akceptujem" id="agree"> Agree therms of use
        </label>
        <button>Create ACC</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: it's on same line in the snippet

Comment: add `* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. `inline-block` elements are rendered in line as element tag, so if your HTML tag is not in line, it will render the formatted code and converts the next line into a whitespace.

Besides Radu Marinescu's solution you might also just try this to prevent it:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2><!--
--><h2>New account</h2>
```

Or

```
<h2>Sign in</h2
><h2>New account</h2>
```

Or negative margin like in CSS example `margin-left:-4px`

Or wrap the elements with a  div container and give it `font-size:0`

Or you can even skip the closing tag and it will ignore the gap.

```
<h2>Sign in
<h2>New account
```

HTML5 doesn't care about closing tags on inline-block elements but I wouldn't recommend this due to parsing reasons e.g JavaScript or some back-end code and SEO purposes.

Or [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) instead

Or use [flexbox](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF)

[David Walsh prettily explains it incl. solutions at his blog](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

When using inline-block elements, make sure you take into consideration the space characters between them. These elements follow the normal flow of the text, being separated by one blank-space character if such characters are found in HTML.

Write the two tags on the same line, without a space between them, and they will fit on the same line: https://jsfiddle.net/9vbqwcm0/2/

```html
<h2>Sign in</h2><h2>New account</h2>

<!-- Instead of:

<h2>Sign in</h2>
<h2>New account</h2>

-->
```

Comment: thanks a lot both of you... again i learned something :)